# Is there any implementation of the Phonegap API using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, node-webkit

I have created a mobile app for Android and iOs, it used some parts of the Phonegap API (connection, FileAPI, FileTransfer, camera, audio)

The mobile app is responsive and works offline, my plan is to create a Desktop version for Windows, Linux and Mac using NodeWebkit https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit so I'm looking for an implementation or ideas of how to implement the Phonegap API using Node.js

As far as I know, it will be possible to implement this APIs:

Connection: Using Node dns module
FileAPI: Using Node file implementation
FileTransfer: Using the http module
Camera: Using WebRTC Chrome APIS
Audio: Using WebRTC Chrome media APIs

Do you think that the node modules mentioned are the appropriate ones? Do you know any current implementation of Phonegap APIs using Node.js?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [**sails.js**](http://sailsjs.org) framework, built on node.js. You can use phonegap and bootstrap both with sails.

Answer (score 1):

I found this one: https://github.com/xverges/cordova-nodewebkit

The problem is that it's not active.